# debug.log is empty in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I've set `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to true in `wp-config.php`, but `wp-content/debug.log` is not being created. wp-content folder has the right permissions.
What's the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: Have you triggered an error? E.g. run `$i = 1/0;`, that should create your debug log with a Division by zero warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That didn't create `debug.log`.